# "Cannot read property 'setCallback' of undefined" in "window.setTimeout"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, error, timeout

I'm trying to call a function every 10 seconds. But I'm getting this error: `Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setCallback' of undefined]`. What is wrong?

```
doGet : function(component, event, helper) {
    let that = this;
    let getTools = component.get("c.getTools");

    getTools.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        let state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.toolObjects", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });           
    $A.enqueueAction(getTools);

    window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            console.log('Calling');
            that.doGet(component);
        }), 10000
    );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the wrong variable in your setCallback

```
let that = this;
let getToolsAction = component.get("c.getTools");

getToolsAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {...
$A.enqueueAction(getToolsAction);
```

Comment: Sorry. Yes. Changed. But the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have written doGet method in controller.js instead of helper.js.

```
 window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            console.log('Calling');
            that.doGet(component);
        }), 10000
    );
```

In above code **that.doGet(component);** will always throw error as **that** will always undefined in controller.js.

Try Change Code like below should resolve your problem.

**Controller.js**

```
doGet : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.doGet(component, event);
    }
```

**helper.js**

```
doGet:function(component,event) {
        let that = this;
        let getAccounts = component.get("c.getAccounts");

        getAccounts.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            let state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.toolObjects", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });           
        $A.enqueueAction(getAccounts);

        window.setTimeout(
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                console.log('Calling');
                that.doGet(component);
            }), 100
        );
    },
```

Comment: No. It's actually in helper :) I call it in controller in `doInit`.

Comment: Actually you have added helper in function parameter so thought you have created in controller. Can you please add log after line let getTools = component.get("c.getTools"); to get getTools has value or not?